# Need quick help on rainfall statistics program

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

basically I am having a pretty rough time on putting together this program that is designed to ask the users how many years of data they want to see, and based on that input, that is how many sets of 12 months of random double rainfall values are displayed.

This is what the output should look like if the user entered 3 years :

Enter the number of years: 3

Year 1 rainfall amounts were

Month 1 rainfall amount was 4.16
Month 2 rainfall amount was 6.85
Month 3 rainfall amount was 1.28
Month 4 rainfall amount was 1.66
Month 5 rainfall amount was 3.06
Month 6 rainfall amount was 4.62
Month 7 rainfall amount was 5.69
Month 8 rainfall amount was 1.84
Month 9 rainfall amount was 9.63
Month 10 rainfall amount was 8.60
Month 11 rainfall amount was 3.34
Month 12 rainfall amount was 1.27

Year 2 rainfall amounts were

Month 1 rainfall amount was 4.38
Month 2 rainfall amount was 4.64
Month 3 rainfall amount was 8.27
Month 4 rainfall amount was 3.19
Month 5 rainfall amount was 6.69
Month 6 rainfall amount was 4.13
Month 7 rainfall amount was 8.52
Month 8 rainfall amount was 5.71
Month 9 rainfall amount was 3.91
Month 10 rainfall amount was 9.16
Month 11 rainfall amount was 3.47
Month 12 rainfall amount was 7.90

Year 3 rainfall amounts were

Month 1 rainfall amount was 2.73
Month 2 rainfall amount was 2.92
Month 3 rainfall amount was 7.98
Month 4 rainfall amount was 2.82
Month 5 rainfall amount was 3.73
Month 6 rainfall amount was 3.00
Month 7 rainfall amount was 0.14
Month 8 rainfall amount was 9.98
Month 9 rainfall amount was 5.34
Month 10 rainfall amount was 8.12
Month 11 rainfall amount was 8.66
Month 12 rainfall amount was 4.21

Number of months: 36
Total rainfall: 181.62 inches
Average monthly rainfall: 5.04 inches

What I have thus far is :

```
import java.util.*;


/**
  This class creates a program that finds the amount of rainfall for each year
*/
public class RainfallStats {
/**
  The main method is the program's starting point 
*/
public static void main(String[] args){

  int years = 0;
  double months = 0;
  final int numberMonths = 12;

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random generator = new Random();

  System.out.println("Enter the number of years: ");
  years = keyboard.nextInt();

  while (years <1){
     System.out.println("Invalid. Enter at least one year");
     years = keyboard.nextInt();
  }

  for (int y = 1; y <= years; y++){

      System.out.println("Year " + y + " rainfall amounts were");
      System.out.println();
  }    

     for (int m = 1; m <= numberMonths; m++){

        System.out.println("Month " + m + " rainfall amount was ");
```

I just need help in the loop and figuring out how to place a different random double value after each of the month statements. I know I probably have some things out of order and am missing quite a bit, but I would appreciate any hints or tips. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a maximum amount of rainful `maxRainfall`, which would be a `final` variable, you can get a random decimal using the `nextDouble` function of `java.util.Random`, and multiplying it by your `maxRainfall`:

```
double monthRainfall = generator.nextDouble() * maxRainfall
```

Then you can do whatever you wish with that new random double, which will be between `0` and `maxRainfall`

To output the months after the appropriate year, instead of all the years then all the months, nest your for loop for the months inside the for loop for the years:

```
for (int y = 1; y <= years; y++)
{
    System.out.println("Year " + y + " rainfall amounts were");
    System.out.println();
    for (int m = 1; m <= numberMonths; m++)
    {
        System.out.println("Month " + m + " rainfall amount was ");
        //Code to generate random double here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate that. Do you have any idea on how I can make my loop repeat with the year followed by the 12 months? As of right now, all of the years are displayed first followed by months 1-12, not 12 months after each increasing year based on the input.

Comment: @Drewmeister96 Nest the for loop for your months inside the for loop for your years, after you `println` the current year. I'll edit post to reflect

Comment: OH! I see now. I had it as a completely different loop. Thanks! I have my setup correct now, but I am still having a hard time understanding how to make each month's rainfall a different random double. I followed what you said above and it created a random double, but it is the same for all of the months. Did I possibly enter the output statement wrong? (I am very new to this if you cannot tell.)

Comment: @Drewmeister96 You have to generate the random double inside the for loop for the months, otherwise it will remain the same

Comment: Thank you so much, I have everything perfect and formatted, and ready to go except one calculation is giving me some trouble. I am trying to find the sum of all of the random values, how would I go about getting that?

Comment: create a variable at the start of your program, a double, to hold the values, then after you generate the number in the for loop, add it to that variable.